Shopify - {Id}.ngrok-free.app refused to connect error
Creating shopify app just for the first time. I followed the steps from below
https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/getting-started/create#step-3-install-your-app-on-your-development-store
Works great up section 3 but after step 2 under section 3, I just keep receiving below error

I did connect to ngrok locally

I was able to run below command successfully as well
PS C:\shopify\testappname> shopify app dev --tunnel-url https://XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-810e-ea3e-6b08-d392.ngrok-free.app:8080

After pressing p and when I install the app selecting development store, I am seeing the error in 1st screenshot saying
XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-810e-ea3e-6b08-d392.ngrok-free.app refused to connect
Any directions to fix above error would be helpful.

You can check by directly hitting the ngrok url that whether the url is reachable or not, also can check that when accessing ngrok url, the terminal running ngrok start logging the request.

I think you're using the wrong port in ngrok. this command is using port 8080 shopify app dev --tunnel-url https://XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-810e-ea3e-6b08-d392.ngrok-free.app:8080 and ngrok is using port 80, try running ngrok with the same port ngrok http 8080
